# How to average regression analyses?

Tags: regression, mean

I have a few hundred of regression analyses liner and I need to figure out will the relationships are mostly positive or negative.

Context: Data is of a parameter reported over time. Reporting was done over different periods of time and has random frequency meaning parameter may have been reported 5 times in a duration of a minute and next parameter was reported after a day. Also one reporting period may be 5 days another 55 days. Parameter itself changes over time following a waveform within a day and a more general waveform for longer periods like weeks or months. Meaning if the parameter is on the overall rise daily fluctuations range becomes higher. The overall rise during the period of reporting is what needs to be identified.

Goal: Primary: Has the parameter decreased or increased on average throughout the duration of reporting (binary)?
Secondary: By how much on average?

P.S. I literally first time heard what a regression is yesterday and using only linear ones. I would appreciate if you would idiotsplain your answers :)

Comment: "I literally first time heard what a regression is yesterday" — Then I doubt you know enough to do this analysis right now, even with guidance from an expert. You should either have an expert do it or give yourself enough time to learn the basics. Doing data analysis well is hard.

Comment: I agree, However before hiring someone I need to know at least more likely outcome of the analysis

Comment: You need to take some courses, preferably in grad school, on statistics. Ideally, you would get a graduate degree in stat or some related fields.

Comment: @PeterFlom This was soo long ago! It is funny to see a recent comment. I think I talked with a seasoned scientist to get fundamentals that I was able to code fairly brute force solution.

Comment: @PovilasID Things show up in my stream from long ago, sometimes.